# Batch Script: Closes on space and certain characters from user input

Tags: batch-file

In the batch script I've created there are certain times where it looks at user input and does functions accordingly based on IF statements. If the user input doesn't match it will ask for input again. The issue I'm running across is if the user inputs a space, <, >, ;, etc. the program abruptly terminates. I've tried adding if statements to catch them and added @ECHO ON to look at the interaction but it seems to die just as the user presses enter. Any ideas on how to avoid this?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMD has many characters that have special meaning that are often referred to as "poison characters" because they can lead to many unwanted effects if they are exposed to the batch parser. Examples include `&` `|` `>` `<` - there are more.

Generally, the characters do not cause problems if they are either quoted like `">"`, or escaped like `^>`. But you don't have control over what the user enters. Some values simply are not safe to work with using normal expansion. For example, if the user enters `This & that "& the other thing"`, then there is no way to add quotes around the value such that both `&` are quoted.

Thankfully, delayed expansion provides a simple solution. Instead of expanding a variable using `%VAR%`, you use `!VAR!`. The variable is expanded *after* the parser finishes looking at all the characters, so the poison characters do not cause any problem. Delayed expansion must first be enabled by using `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`

Here is a simple demonstration that will successfully ECHO any value the user types in, no matter what poison characters are present. You can easily adapt the code to an IF statement.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /p "var=Enter a string: "
echo You entered: !var!
```

Comment: This helped a lot. Right now all the user input looks similar to this:

`SET /p "INPUT=What would you like to do? "`

This then does a call to a subroutine to check the input:

`CALL :InputCheck`

Which looks like this:

`:InputCheck
IF /I "!INPUT!"=="PING" CALL :Ping & GOTO %Menu%`
And others like it.

This resolved the issues with spaces and ; causing errors, however the poison characters (`& | < >`) are problem.

Comment: Never mind, all is well. I have to remember to not edit the batch while editing/saving as it causes unpredictable results. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes will protect against spaces and most of the poison characters.  The IF comparisons need them too.

```
set /p "variable=Enter your input: "
echo "%variable%"
if "%variable%"=="string" execute program
```